# OVerlaying sharepoint calendar with a outlook calendar

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-calendar, exchange

you have this option in sharpeoint calendar, to overlay it with another calendar or with a exchange calendar. I tried adding an exchange calendar but it doesn't work. It says there no end listening to the exchange url. I know it's correct i use it in another app and it works. I copy pasted the url so there's no typo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the URL to be typed in Exchange web service URL is

https://Yourpublishedserver/ews/exchange.asmx

I guess the problem is if your exchange allows external entities (such as sp) to access it.

Comment: in my case the url look like this https://mail.info.eu/ews/exchange.asmx And it doesn't work

Comment: what about https or http and is the SP starting with https or http?

Comment: By default it's https.If i try with http it says something like it has to be https

Comment: next step is to ask the exchange admin if the exchange url is published externally